# getting authenticated user info from passportjs and express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have an express application that uses passport for OAuth. I have it working successfully with Google and Facebook. My problem is that I can get req.user on controller functions where the routes are configured like this:

```
router.post('/', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.create);
```

but when I try to access the user info from a controller function that doesn't require authentication, req.user is undefined even though the user is logged in. What am I doing wrong here?

and here is how express and passport are configured:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var env = app.get('env');

  app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(methodOverride());
  app.use(cookieParser());



  // Persist sessions with mongoStore
  // We need to enable sessions for passport twitter because its an oauth 1.0 strategy
  app.use(session({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new mongoStore({ mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection })
  }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
.
.
.
```